# How to install Qt Serialport on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, serial-port, qmake

I'm trying to compile [this code](https://github.com/SimulIDE/SimulIDE03/tree/dev) where the `.pro` file includes a

```
QT += serialport
```

gives me a

> Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: serialport

error. Without Qt, I would use CMake and install the package via vcpkg, Conan, HomeBrew, or something like that. But not sure if Qt has its own package manager. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the most canonical way to install and include this library.

**P.S.1.** In the comments, I'm being told that I need to use Qt's Maintenance Tool, which is sorta the internal package manager for Qt, to install `QtSerialPort` module. Given that [I don't know](https://forum.qt.io/post/590695) how to install that via HomeBrew, I installed Qt Creator from the Qt website. I found the Maintenance Tool in `<install_dir>` the installation folder `/Users/<user>/Qt/MaintenanceTool.app` which I could open from the terminal by `open MaintenanceTool.app` while being in that folder. However, I can not see any `QtSerialPort` module in the options, nor a way to search.

**P.S.2.** Posted a new question [here](https://forum.qt.io/post/590743).

**P.S.3.** I think this issue arises because I had multiple versions of Qt installed. once I searched for `locate qmake` and found out the other versions I have installed (e.g., `/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/bin/qmake`) I could just run that and the `MakeFile` was generated.

Comment: If you have used the online installer then you must use the maintenance tool to install the serialport module.

Comment: @eyllanesc No, I did not use the online installer. Is it possible to install it via HomeBrew? I don't want to install things manually.

Comment: Yes, your update is correct .. modules like `serialport` , `network` , `printing` are optional but core parts ..  However , are you sure of the error ... I checked the repo .. its also using Qt `script` which requires installing the option .. , as final check , it could happen that you have 2 Qt installations and one is broken.

Comment: @MohammadKanan I actually have multiple Qt installed as explained [here](https://forum.qt.io/post/590695). However, when opening the maintenance tool I can't see any `QtSerialPort` module. Any idea how/where it should be found/installed?

Comment: Qt Maintenance tool has nothing to do with your problem. On the other hand you seem having Qt4 (Pre-history version of Qt, I don't know why installed on your system) which also not the correct version of your repository  .. If you dont know why  Qt4 installed on your system .. you might want to remove it to the advantage of working with Qt5 .. the issue _might_ resolve .. cause I don't remember `serialport` was separate package in Qt4 or not .. I mean this could be the problem

Comment: Also on your macOS, which qmake is the default ?  `which qmake` ... you will learn better what exactly is happening

Comment: @MohammadKanan this is the result `/usr/local/bin/qmake`

Comment: In short, You need to make sure that Qt5 is the active Qt on your system .. I think `qmake --version` would tell you what Qt version is ..

Comment: @MohammadKanan here is the return `QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/local/lib`