# compiling gpsim on macOS causes "error: 'long long type-name' is invalid"

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, clang

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61397688/4999991), I'm trying to compile [this code](https://github.com/SimulIDE/SimulIDE03/tree/dev) on macOS. I ran

```
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/bin/qmake
```

inside the `build_XX` folder successfully, and then `make`. However, I get the compiling error:

```
../src/gpsim/protocol.cc:79:8: error: 'long long type-name' is invalid
  uint long long i = ascii2uint64(buffer, digits);
       ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build/release/protocol.o] Error 1
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/hybridgroup/go-ncs/pull/4#issuecomment-420668195), I added

```cpp
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <sys/types.h>
#endif // __APPLE__
```

at the top of the `protocol.cc` file with no avail. I would appreciate it if you could help me understand what is the problem and how I can solve it. Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such type as `uint long long`.

There is `long long` and `unsigned long long`.

Qt also provides `qlonglong`.

Comment: so this is a bug, with any other compiler as well? and has nothing to do with macOS or clang for that matter?

Comment: OP mentioned Qt. Qt does in fact provide [`uint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#uint-typedef). Hence, I'm a bit puzzled why `uint long long` shouldn't work. Of course, I didn't dig deeper. A missing Qt header might explain...

Comment: @Foad As far as I know, yes.

Comment: it worked, but I will be waiting for @JesperJuhl to see why Qt doesn't work properly here.

Comment: On [gpsim source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/gpsim/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/protocol.cc#l79), it is also `unsigned long long`. Wonder why the software I have forked has changed it. 

Comment: @Foad Too funny that I noticed two last commits in the linked github repo with something like "long long fixed" which appeared just 13 minutes (!) before you sent your question... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff yeah, I committed but the line is still there commented out. I was waiting for your feedback to see why Qt doesn't work as it is expected.